# Intuition for the compactness of real projective space $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, intuition, smooth-manifolds

I want to have an intuition for why the $n$-dimensional real projective space defined as $$\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n:=\mbox{set of 1-dimensional subspaces of }\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$ is compact. I don't see how it is bounded since the subspaces can "extend" to as much as I want.

But I know the proof:

> Define a relation on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ via $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow \ x=\lambda y, \ \lambda\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.$ Then, w.r.t. this equivalence relation, $$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}/\sim \ \equiv \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n.$$   There is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n \mbox{ to } \mathbb{S}^n/\sim$ where $x\sim -x, \forall x\in \mathbb{S}^n$. It is $$f:\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n/\sim, \ [x]\mapsto \bigg[\frac{x}{||x||}\bigg].$$ The compactness of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ follows from $\mathbb{S}^n/\sim$ being compact.

To repeat: My question is about having an intuition. I cannot see how $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is bounded. Perhaps, you should give me the precise set that will contain $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n.$

Comment: The subspaces themselves are unbounded, like you said, but that's irrelevant because each subspace corresponds to a single point in $RP^n$. I think the best way to think about $RP^n$ is as a quotient of $S^{n}$, precisely as you described.

Comment: Your definition of the projective space is insufficient. You only define it as a set, so compactness means nothing. The set in question can be given compact and noncompact topologies. Did your definition come with a topology? The one induced from $\mathbb S^n/{\sim}$? (The subspaces themselves are not compact, but that is irrelevant. They are merely points in the projective space.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, yes it is induced from $S^n/\sim$.

Comment: The $1$-dimensional subspaces are *points* of $\mathbb{RP}^n$. As such, they do not extend in any direction. You can define the distance between two such points as the angle between corresponding $1$-dimensional subspaces. This angle is at most $\frac\pi2$, so the distance between each two points is bounded.

Comment: If your definition says that the projective space is topologically $\mathbb S^n/{\sim}$, then it is automatically compact. Your proof seems to have no topological content...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I should have said that the projective space has a quotient topology induced from a map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n,x\mapsto [x]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An open set in $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is basically an open cone in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, or it can also be seen as just an open set on $S^{n}$ that is symmetric abot the origin, so $U \subset S^n$ such that $U = -U$. Thus any open cover of $S^n$ gives an open cover of the sphere. More generally the point is that every ray corresponds (uniuqe up to sign) to a point on the sphere, so though the rays look unbounded the point is. For yet another perspective, by quotienting the rays down to points, you are basically killing the unbounded part of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

"Bounded" isn't really the right intuitive notion to be thinking about, because the topology of $\mathbb R \mathbb P^n$ is not defined by a metric.  Instead, I think the clearest intuition comes from thinking about sequential compactness: Every sequence in $\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ has a convergent subsequence.  (For manifolds, compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent.)

Suppose $\{\xi_i\}$ is any sequence of points in $\mathbb R \mathbb P^n$ (i.e., any sequence of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$).  Each $\xi_i$ intersects the unit sphere in two points, say $\{x_i,-x_i\}$.  Because $\mathbb S^n$ is compact, the sequence $\{x_i\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{i_j}\}$.  And because the quotient map $q\colon \mathbb R^{n+1}\smallsetminus \{0\}\to \mathbb P^n$ is continuous, it follows that $\xi_{i_j} = q(x_{i_j})$ converges.

Tl;dr: $1$-dimensional subspaces are determined by where they meet the unit sphere, and compactness of the sphere guarantees that subspaces can't wander too far away.